# How i can center and fixed a modal windows with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have some small problem now with modal jquery window. I have defined it as:

```
function mywin() {
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 460,
            modal: true,
        show: {
            effect: "drop",
            duration: 3000,
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "drop",
            duration: 1000
        },
            buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "EXIT": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
        });
    });
}
```

And all ok. I need that it result to center of Windows (horiz and vert) too when user resize it and result fixed to center Always.

About centering to parent window when i load it first time is ok, but after first time the modal window result not perfectly centered in vertical but little under respect the exact position. Just i do a refresh of page then it take correct position in vertical. 
Other problem with centering is when i resize browser Windows. The modal window not update position respect to new center.
I have tried to search something in this site as for example:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").position({
   my: "center",
   at: "center",
   of: window
});
```

but the problem not solved.
So first question is: how i can to do for have modal window Always to center of browser too when user resize it ?

About second question, how i can solve becouse the modal window is fixed Always to center?
Too for this i have searched here something and found suggest about add a class with `position:fixed` but i have saw that the Windows not is fixed and i can Always move it on the screen.

Then very much for who can help me to fix this two problem.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can use Fancybox or something similar? It does what you want and more without any coding on your part: http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Nathaniel, i have posted full code under for try to explain better the probem. But you tell well. The reason are two: first becouse i Learning too use jquery and so i take good reason for it and second becouse is good idea of course use something of ready and tested but is too true that often it need more time and not Always for work it possible, In this case first reason is that mainly relavant (about me and Learning it).

Comment: I understand. All good.

Answer (score 0):

*Many questions...*

In CSS

```
#dialog-confirm {
    position: fixed;
}
```

would set any HTML element to float above others always **sticked** in the same position of your screen. So, this is probably what you need as starting point for the modal window.

In JS

You should set to the window:

```
var posx = (screen.width() - $("#dialog-confirm").width()) / 2;
var posy = (screen.height() - $("#dialog-confirm").height()) / 2;
$("#dialog-confirm").offset({ top: posy , left: posx })
```

**[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** comes with a good modal window and a working CSS and JS solution to all this issues.

Many modal windows have a vertical centering problem I won't argue this.

This is to detect the resize of the viewport/browser:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var posx = (screen.width() - $("#dialog-confirm").width()) / 2;
        var posy = (screen.height() - $("#dialog-confirm").height()) / 2;
        $("#dialog-confirm").offset({ top: posy , left: posx })
    });
});
```

Stop reinventing the wheel unless you are just learning :)

Comment: About these solution something i found before; now i try again copying your suggest. Yes is true, with jquery i am beginning from few. I working with it mainly for solve a problem about cookie law. And so i studying a solution about it. Server side is all ok and same too about management of cookie server/client side but about gui it yet not perfect. :)

Comment: I will fully recommend to learn a little about BOOTSTRAP. It's really easy, it will solve all your frontend (HTML + CSS + JS) basic needs. Much easier than learning CSS and jQuery for standard functionality and visual components.